# Avoiding auto-increment ID collisions when moving data between MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql

So the situation is that I am going to have two or more "insert" machines where my web application just inserts data that we want to log into the machines (they are all behind a load balancer). Every couple hours, one by one the machines will be disconnected from the load balancer and upload their information into the "master" database machine should have a relatively up to date version of all the data we are collecting.

Originally I was going to use mysqldump, but found that you cannot specify the command to not grab the auto_increment id column I have (which would lead to collisions on primary key). I saw another post recommending using a temporary table to put the data in and then drop the column, but the "insert" machines have very low specs, and the amount of data could be pretty significant on the order of 50,000 rows. Other than just programatically just taking x rows at a time and inserting them into the remote "master" database, is there an easier way to do this? Currently I have php installed on the "insert" machines.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the master database record to have the same primary key for each record as the slave database? If not, that could lead to problems where a query will produce different results based on which machine it's on. A better solution might be to use a primary key that can be guaranteed to be unique, so there won't be collisions. For example, you could concatenate the unix time (with microseconds) with an identifier that's different for each server.

Comment: The key is meaningless, it is basically just a counter. There is no information of use, other than it is unique, and generally relates to when the record was inserted into the "master" database.

Comment: Oh, and there are never any reads from the table I am exporting from the slave machines. The whole point is they only have to deal with inserts.

Comment: Sounds like a job for UUID or GUID.

Comment: xenocross: agreed, but do you have a good reference on how to automatically generate a unique server prefix, without having to have unique code on each server? I assume the simplest solution is to pull something from $_SERVER that already differs between the servers, but I don't know what to pick off the top of my head.

Comment: I want to stress the point that I do not care what ID the data has, and when they are moved from slave to master I do not care that the rows are no longer identifiable by their slave id. It is really just a way to easily give each row a unique column, and I knew from the start that it was going to be lost in transit. What I did not realize is that I am going to have to move a bunch of data on really slow servers. I am talking like 1.3 MBs or RAM and like one 2 GHZ processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you want the master database record to have the same primary key for each record as the slave database? If not, that could lead to problems where a query will produce different results based on which machine it's on.

If you want an arbitrary primary key that will avoid collisions, consider removing the auto-increment ID and constructing an ID that's guaranteed to be unique for every record on each server. For example, you could concatenate the unix time (with microseconds) with an identifier that's different for each server. A slightly lazier solution would be to concatenate time + a random 10-digit number or something. PHP's uniqid() function does something like this automatically.

If you don't intend to ever use the ID, then just remove it from your tables. There's no rule saying that every table has to have a primary key. If you don't use it, but you want to encode information about when each record was inserted, add a timestamp column instead (and don't make it a key).

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose this is true. I just always felt like a table is supposed to have a primary key. Is this your opinion that every table does not need a primary key, or is it something people agree is not necessary is every case?

Comment: I don't see any reason a primary key is necessary for every database, but I don't have a specific reference for it. If you want to be sure of always being able to uniquely specify each record, it might be wise to assign some other primary key (which could be a composite of several fields).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended ridding myself of the primary key field.